# grafana desn't want to provision dashbords file

Tags: kubernetes, grafana

I'm trying to run Grafana on kuberentes and keep getting on this error message:

lvl=eror msg="Server shutdown" logger=server error="*provisioning.ProvisioningServiceImpl run error: Failed to create provisioner: Failed to read dashboards config: could not parse provisioning config file: dashboards.yaml error: read /etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/dashboards.yaml: is a directory

My grafana deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: grafana
  name: grafana
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: grafana
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: grafana
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 472
        supplementalGroups:
          - 0
      containers:
        - name: grafana
          image:  grafana/grafana:8.3.4
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
              name: http-grafana
              protocol: TCP
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /robots.txt
              port: 3000
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 30
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 2
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            tcpSocket:
              port: 3000
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 250m
              memory: 750Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /etc/grafana/provisioning
              name: grafana-pv
              subPath: provisioning
            - mountPath: '/var/lib/grafana/grafana.ini'
              name: grafana-ini
              
              
            # - mountPath: '"{{ grafana_dir }}"/datasources/datasources.yml'
            #   name: grafana-datasources
            #   subPath: "datasources.yml"
            - mountPath: '/etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/dashboards.yml'
              name: grafana-dashboards
              subPath: dashboards.yml
             
            - mountPath: '/etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/Home.json'
              name: grafana-home
              subPath: "Home.json"

      volumes:
        - name: grafana-pv
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mypvc
        - name: grafana-ini
          configMap:
            defaultMode: 0777
            name: grafana-ini
        - name: grafana-dashboards
          configMap:
            defaultMode: 0777
            name: grafana-dashboards
        # - name: grafana-datasources
        #   configMap:
        #     defaultMode: 0777
        #     name: grafana-datasources
        - name: grafana-home
          configMap:
            defaultMode: 0777
            name: grafana-home
```

and my dashboards.yml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: grafana-dashboards
data:
  dashboards.yml: |-
    {
        apiVersion: 1
        providers:
          # Folders
          - name: 'test1Status'
            folder: 'test1Status'
            folderUid: 'test1'
            options:
              path: /etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/test1
          - name: 'test2Status'
            folder: 'test2Status'
            folderUid: 'test2'
            options:
              path: /etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/test2

          # Separate dashboards (General folder)
          - name: 'Versions info'
            options:
              path: /etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/Versions-info.json
          - name: 'Home'
            options:
              path: /etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/Home.json
          - name: 'Namespaces'
            options:
              path: /etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/Namespaces.json

    }
```

Comment: The error message references `/etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/dashboards.yaml`, but you're mounting `/etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/dashboards.yml` (note the difference in the extension).

Comment: That is something that I'm also wondering about, in previous version of the file I had /etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/dashboards.yaml file, but now it doesn't exist, so I'm wondering if it's because I didn't delete something from my namespace.